# Joda DateTime toDate returns not as per Created DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Hi I noticed that Joda DateTime created using Zone is returning toDate as per Current System Date. I was expecting toDate to return as per Created DateTime. As per Joda API, it says **toDate should return Date initialised with this datetime**. I am using Joda 2.9.4 in my Maven. Any thoughts from Gurus out in SO

```
public class TestJodaError {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime ldt = new DateTime();
    System.out.println("Local dt: " + ldt + " toDate: " + ldt.toDate());

    String tzId = "Asia/Singapore";
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(tzId);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);

    DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID(zdt.getZone().getId());
    DateTime rdt = new DateTime(dtZone);
    System.out.println("Remote dt: " + rdt + " toDate: " + rdt.toDate());
}}
```

Results are

```
Local dt: 2019-05-17T11:33:30.333+05:30 toDate: Fri May 17 11:33:30 IST 2019
Remot dt: 2019-05-17T14:03:30.738+08:00 toDate: Fri May 17 11:33:30 IST 2019
```

Expected Results

```
Remot dt: 2019-05-17T14:03:30.738+08:00 toDate: Fri May 17 14:03:30 SGT 2019
```

Comment: toDate is your custom function? I couldnot find it in Joda [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)

Comment: Without Zoda time, you can achieve using Java 8.

Comment: @BilboBaggins perhaps it's actually a `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Not sure, I been using Java 8, java.time and not Joda time. Was just trying to solve the question. :)

Comment: toDate Method is from Joda DateTime

Comment: You are losing information twice in your operation: (1) A Joda-Time `DateTime` has a UTC offset, but no time zone, so `rdt` doesn’t know that it is from Singapore, only that its offset it `+08:00`. (2) As others have said, an old-fashioned `Date` neither has got offset nor time zone, so just prints in your JVM’s default time zone regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andy mentioned, Date will not have any specific time zone info. If you want to use without Joda time and want to leverage Java 8, I provide below the code snippet.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.MAY, 17, 11, 30);
ZonedDateTime klDateTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
DateTimeFormatter indianFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy");

String output = klDateTime.format(indianFormat);
```

Answer (score 2):

Printing a `java.util.Date` will always use the JVM's default time zone, because `Date` doesn't actually contain any time zone information.

As such, printing the result of `rdt.toDate()` will print in IST if `ldt.toDate()` also prints in IST.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that shows why... Was under the assumption that toDate from Joda DateTime will follow accordingly.